# Creating a View or Materialized View to refresh constantly

Tags: sql-server, view, refresh, materialized-views

I am trying to create either a view or a materialized view (i don't know which one to use) that takes a complex select statement with joins, filters, and unions and constantly refreshes it.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You create both (regular one and materialized) and compare performance.

Comment: Never been a fan of views (materialized or not), they can get expensive,  Have you considered a Table-Value Function instead?

Comment: Can you please give me the syntax for creating both and how would i get them to refresh?

Comment: Views don't store data so there is no concept of "getting them to refresh". If you want to view the current data in a view you simply run a select statement from the view. Now a materialized view is another story, it does in fact materialize the data. However, you still don't "refresh" it yourself. Seems you should spend a little time in the documentation so you understand what you are proposing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-materialized-view-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest